# ASIHTTPRequest setDownloadDestinationPath crashing

Tags: asihttprequest

I have this simple code:

```
NSURL *urltmp = downloadContentURL;
NSURL *url = [urltmp URLByAppendingPathComponent:file];
NSLog(@"url is: %@", url);
ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDownloadDestinationPath:[self applicationSupportDirectoryWithFilename:file]];

[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
[request setShowAccurateProgress:YES];
[request setDownloadProgressDelegate:self];

[request startAsynchronous];
```

I am using setDownloadDestinationPath in order to write the file to disk directly, and not in memory. The file is 80MB so is crashing on the device when downloading in memory.

Code works fine in the simulator, but on the device is crashing with:

Thread 2: Program received signal: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION.
  [((ASIHTTPRequest*)clientCallBackInfo) handleNetworkEvent: type];

Please assist

regards,
Bill.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by swapping minimum build settings from 4.0 to 4.1. 
Maybe something was missing from 4.0.

Thanks...